# Efficient representation for variable-order Markov Chain

Tags: string-matching, markov-chains

Recall that a (fixed-order) Markov Chain can be considered as a Finite State Automaton with edges labelled by transition probabilities.

Hence, a transition in a second-order Markov Chain can be considered as a map

```
trans2: (State,State) -> List[(State,Float)]
```

Where the float value represents the transition probability associated with the target state.

Extending this in the obvious fashion to the variable-order case gives:

```
transN: List[State] -> List[(State,Float)]
```

However, the implementation of this mapping for some input List(state1, ..., stateM ) requires finding all LHS entries in the transition table which are a (not necessarily proper) prefix of the List(state1, ..., stateM ).

**Q.** Given that the number of states might be large, what might be a good representation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An efficient representation of Variable Length Markov Chain (VLMC) is as a Probabilistic Suffix Tree (PST). Look for instance at the article [1] about the `PST` R-package.

[1]: Gabadinho, A. and Ritschard, G. (2016). Analyzing State Sequences with Probabilistic Suffix Trees: The PST R Package. *Journal of Statistical Software*, 72(3), 1-39. https://www.jstatsoft.org/article/view/v072i03